# Extract first occurrence of <title> from specific web-page with CSS selectors does not work

Tags: html, curl, css-selectors

I have the following command that extracts 4  results from one single web-page :

```
$ curl -qLs https://vimeo.com/groups/57545/videos/37660976 | hxnormalize -x | hxselect -s '\n' 'title' 
<title>#258 The Holy Spirit Convicts Us of Righteousness on Vimeo</title>
<title>Menu</title>
<title>Search</title>
<title>Search</title>
```

I tried the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class but it does not work as I expect :

```
$ curl -qLs https://vimeo.com/groups/57545/videos/37660976 | hxnormalize -x | hxselect -s '\n' 'title:first-of-type' 
<title>#258 The Holy Spirit Convicts Us of Righteousness on Vimeo</title>
<title>Menu</title>
<title>Search</title>
<title>Search</title>
```

I want to do that with CSS selectors.

N.B.: The `hxnormalize` and `hxselect` tools come from [html-xml-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/).

Comment: Note that having multiple `title` elements is invalid in HTML.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't have access to vimeo to correct the HTML code of their webpages.

Comment: Never said you did. Just noting that the HTML is invalid, which makes things more challenging than it needs to be, and is something answerers should be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -m 1 '<title>'` which will only return the first match, like:

```
curl -qLs https://vimeo.com/groups/57545/videos/37660976 | grep -m 1 '<title>'
```

Or you can use some regex to get the first `<title>` tag which is inside the `<head>` tag like:

```
curl -qLs https://vimeo.com/groups/57545/videos/37660976 | sed -n '/<head>/,/<\/head>/p' | grep '<title>'
```

Comment: Hi @caramba (lol) Thanks for your answer. However, I want to do that with CSS selectors.